# getting null values while updating array datatype in hive

Tags: hive

I have a hive table created as follows:

`create table arraytbl (id string, model string, cost int, colors array <string>,size array <float>) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' collection items terminated by '#';`

trying to insert few records using the following data which is saved in a file:

`J8,Samsung_J8,12000,(red#blue#green),(8.9#10.4#9.9)
Y2,Redmi_Y2,8000,(violet),(1.5#3.5#1.9)
A1,Samsung_A1,17000,(yellow#white),(1.1#5.5#5.4)
S7,Honor_S7,10000,(shine#dull#new#blue#darkblue#raksha),(1.1#5.5#5.4)
XP,Sony_XP,17000,(bcd#efgh#ikkdla#pdia),(1.4#5.5#8.9#10.4#9.9#5.6)
X,iPhoneX,68000,(adadad),(1.4#5.5#8.9#10.4#9.9#5.8)`

Loading the data using following command:
`load data local inpath 'products.csv' into table arraytbl;`

data gets loaded to the table, select * fetches the result as :

`J8 Samsung_J8  12000   ["(red","blue","green)"]    [null,10.4,null]
Y2  Redmi_Y2    8000    ["(violet)"]    [null,3.5,null]
A1  Samsung_A1  17000   ["(yellow","white)"]    [null,5.5,null]
S7  Honor_S7    10000   ["(shine","dull","new","blue","darkblue","raksha)"] [null,5.5,null]
XP  Sony_XP 17000   ["(bcd","efgh","ikkdla","pdia)"]    [null,5.5,8.9,10.4,9.9,null]
X   iPhoneX 68000   ["(adadad)"]    [null,5.5,8.9,10.4,9.9,null]`

Problem is the unwanted "null" values for the field size which is an array of float. for example, for the first row, filed should have a value of 8.9,10.4,9.9.
whereas values are null,10.4 and null. so the first and the last element in the array is getting null values. this is same for all the rows.

can someone please tell me what is wrong in my query or the data i am using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `colors` array is also loaded wrong:

`["(shine","dull","new","blue","darkblue","raksha)"]` - first and last element have parenthesis. This is quite acceptable for `strings` but not possible to cast for `float` datatype, this is why only first and last float are NULLs.

Remove parenthesis and it will load good.

Alternatively, you can load them in `array<string>`, 
it will result in this: `["(8.9","10.4","9.9)"]` for the first row.
And you can remove parenthesis while selecting